# How to construct the point S of this tetrahedron?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

Let be given tetrahedron `SABC`, where `AB= 3, AC=4, BC=5, SA= 6, SB=7,SC=8`. I tried

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{70}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [tdplot_main_coords,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
        \path
        (0,0,0) coordinate (A)
        (3,0,0)  coordinate (B)
        (0, 4,0) coordinate (C)
        ;
        \draw (C) -- (A) -- (B) -- cycle;
            \path foreach \p/\g in {A/180,B/0,C/90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to get the point `S`?

Comment: That is a math problem

Comment: @John: I guess that you wants to construct the tetradhedron when knowing the lengths of six sides. If so, that is a classical Euclidean geometry problem, anh its solution (algorithm how to construct) is avaiable very long time ago. Do you need a reference for that?

Comment: @BlackMild Yes can you show the link for me? And, How about Asymptote?

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter: Have you checked that `3,4,5,6,7,8` are sides of a tetrahedron? Note that for `a,b,c` be 3 sides of a triangle, we need the triangle inequality `a+b>c`. There is a similar situation for tetrahedron, see this paper *Edge lengths determining tetrahedrons* https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=0013-6018&vol=64&iss=4&rank=4

Comment: @BlackMild Thank you very much. From the paper to latex, I see very difficult. Can you using your link to answer my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**
By using [new update](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools} % https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},
        declare function={lAB=3;lAC=4;lBC=5;lAD=6;lBD=7;lCD=8;}]
        % ^^^ the lengths of the tetrahedron
        \begin{scope}[3d/install view={phi=100,psi=0,theta=70}]
            % construct a triangle of three vertices in the xy plane
            % using the cosine law
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytheta}{acos(-1*(lBC*lBC-lAC*lAC-lAB*lAB)/(2*lAB*lAC))}
            \path (0,0,0) coordinate (A)
            (lAB,0,0) coordinate (B)
            ({lAC*cos(\mytheta)},{lAC*sin(\mytheta)},0) coordinate (C);
            \path[overlay,3d/aux keys/i1=S,3d/aux keys/i2=D',
            3d/intersection of three spheres={rA=lAD,rB=lBD,rC=lCD}];
            \path[3d/circumsphere center={A={(A)},B={(B)},C={(C)},D={(S)}}]
            coordinate (I);
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myR}{sqrt(TD("(I)-(A)o(I)-(A)"))} ;
            \path[3d/circumcircle center={A={(A)},B={(B)},C={(C)}}] coordinate (G);
            \draw[red,3d/screen coords] (I) circle[radius=\myR];
            \path pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=\myR,C={(I)}, P={(G)}}};
            \path[3d/circumcircle center={A={(A)},B={(B)},C={(S)}}] coordinate (T); 
            \path[blue]  pic{3d/circle on sphere={R=\myR,C={(I)}, P={(T)}}};
            \path foreach \p/\g in {A/180,B/-90,C/0,S/90,G/-90,I/0}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}};
            \draw[3d/hidden] (A) -- (C) (S) -- (A)  (S) -- (B) (S) --(C) (A) -- (B) -- (C);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Note that, there are two point `S`. I put them `S` and `S'`. You can use [3dtools](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools). In this code, I add two points `T` and `T'` can be found by Maple to compare with the results of `3dtools`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{3dtools,calc}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=70,theta=70},line cap=butt,line join=round,c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},declare function={r1=6;r2=7;r3=8;}] 
            \path
            (0,0,0) coordinate (A)
            (3,0,0) coordinate (B)
            (0,4,0) coordinate (C)
            (-2/3,-3/2,{sqrt(1199)/6}) coordinate (T)
            (-2/3,-3/2,{-sqrt(1199)/6}) coordinate (T')
            ;  % T and T' are found by Maple
            \path[overlay,3d/aux keys/i1=S,3d/aux keys/i2=S',3d/intersection of three spheres={rA=r1,rB=r2,rC=r3}];
            \path foreach \p/\g in {A/180,B/-90,C/-90,S/0,T/180,S'/0,T'/180}
            {(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** The calculations are from [the 3-D Cartesian true range multilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True-range_multilateration) (in fact, those are formulae for calculating intersections of three spheres). I also add the 3D grid on XY-plane.

[image]

```
unitsize(1cm);
import three;
import grid3;
triple barycentric(triple A, triple B, triple C, real a, real b, real c){return (a*A+b*B+c*C)/(a+b+c);}

currentprojection=orthographic((1,1,.8),center=true,zoom=.9);

// Step 1: construct the base A,B,C on the plane z=0
real a=5, b=4, c=3; 
triple B=(0,0,0), C=(a,0,0);
// Abc is the projection of A on the segment BC
triple Abc=barycentric(B,C,O,1/(a^2+c^2-b^2),1/(a^2+b^2-c^2),0);
real bt=abs(Abc-B);
real hbc=sqrt(c*c-bt*bt);
triple A=Abc+hbc*dir(90,90);
draw(A--B--C--cycle,blue+1pt);
label("$A$",A,plain.S);
label("$B$",B,dir(150));
label("$C$",C,plain.NW);
//label("$A_{bc}$",Abc,plain.N,red);
//draw(A--Abc,red);

// Step 2: get the top point D
real at=6, bt=7, ct=8; 
// H is the projection of D on the base ABC
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True-range_multilateration
real Hx=(bt^2-ct^2+a^2)/(2a);
real Hy=(bt^2-at^2+A.x^2+A.y^2-2A.x*Hx)/(2A.y);
real Dz=sqrt(bt^2-Hx^2-Hy^2);
triple H=(Hx,Hy,0);
triple D=(Hx,Hy,Dz);

draw(D--A^^D--B^^D--C,blue+1pt);
draw(D--H,red+dashed);
label("$D$",D,plain.N);
label("$H$",H,plain.E,red); dot(H,red);

// grid on XY-plane
limits((-2,-2,0),(7,5,0));
grid3(XYXgrid,step=1,.5gray+.5white);
draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint),O--8X,Arrow3());
draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint),O--6Y,Arrow3());
draw(Label("$z$",EndPoint),O--6Z,Arrow3());
write("H = ("+string(H.x)+","+string(H.y)+",0)");
write("DH = "+string(abs(H-D)));
```

[image]

**Old answer** This is a well-known construction problem of Euclidean geometry. In drawing, we can use geometric constructions, but it is better to use computation approaches. Among some computation approaches, I found one using `barycentric coordinate` is more convenient and can be applied for drawing both 2D and 3D figures.

**Problem 1. Triangle on the plane**:  *To construct a triangle ABC on the plane Oxy knowing its 3 lengths a=BC, b=CA, c=AB (provided that the triangle `a + b > c` is fulfilled)*

The usual way is first taking `B` and `C` such that `BC=a`, then `A` is one of two intersection points of the circle centered `B` with radius `c` and the circle centered `C` with radius `b`, using some built-in procedures to find intersection of 2 circle `path`. Here I go with computation approach
using `barycentric coordinate`

```
pair barycentric(pair A=(0,0), pair B=(0,0), real a=1, real b=0){
return (a*A+b*B)/(a+b);}
```

Rewriting the formula in [this my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581208/140722), to get the projection `H` of the `A` on `BC`

```
pair H=barycentric(B,C,1/(a^2+c^2-b^2),1/(a^2+b^2-c^2));
```

Finally, the point `A` is obtained by the Pythagorean theorem in the right triangle `AHB`.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
pair barycentric(pair A=(0,0), pair B=(0,0), real a=1, real b=0){
return (a*A+b*B)/(a+b);}

// Application: construct a triangle knowing the lengths of 3 sides
unitsize(1cm);
real a=6, b=5, c=2.5;
pair B=(0,0), C=(a,0);
pair H=barycentric(B,C,1/(a^2+c^2-b^2),1/(a^2+b^2-c^2));
real bt=abs(H-B);
real h=sqrt(c*c-bt*bt);
pair A=H+h*dir(90);

draw(box(H,H+(.2,.2)),red);
draw(A--H,red);
draw(A--B--C--cycle);
label("$A$",A,plain.N);
label("$B$",B,plain.SW);
label("$C$",C,plain.SE);
label("$H$",H,plain.S);
```

**Problem 2. Triangle on the space**: *To construct a triangle ABC on the space Oxyz knowing its 3 lengths a=BC, b=CA, c=AB (provided that the triangle inequality `a + b > c` is fulfilled)*

This can be done as same as Problem 1 with suitable minor changes (see Step 1 in the code of Problem 3 below).

**Problem 3. Tetrahedron on the space**: *To construct a tetrahedron `D.ABC` on the space Oxyz knowing its 6 lengths (3 lengths of the base `a=BC`, `b=CA`, `c=AB`; and 3 remaining lengths `at=DA`, `bt=DB`, `ct=DC` (provided that some conditions are fulfilled, see [this 2009 EMS paper](http://Edge%20lengths%20determining%20tetrahedrons)).*

We use `barycentric coordinate` 2 times. First construct triangle ABC on some plane, say `z=0`. This is the above Problem 2. Next, get the projection `H` of `D` on the base `ABC`. The Heron formula is used in the barycentric coordinates of `H` (areas are used instead of side lengths)

```
import three;
triple barycentric(triple A, triple B, triple C, real a, real b, real c){return (a*A+b*B+c*C)/(a+b+c);}

real Heron(real a, real b, real c){
real p=(a+b+c)/2;
return sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
}
```

then the desired point `D` is obtained by the Pythagoras theorem in the right triangle `DHA`.

[image]

Full code (still some mistake! I am looking for [barycentric coordinates of the foot of an altitude in a tetrahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269177/barycentric-coordinates-of-the-foot-of-an-altitude-in-a-tetrahedron) - seems an interesting and sensitive situation)

```
unitsize(1cm);
import three;
triple barycentric(triple A, triple B, triple C, real a, real b, real c){return (a*A+b*B+c*C)/(a+b+c);}

real Heron(real a, real b, real c){
real p=(a+b+c)/2;
return sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
}
currentprojection=orthographic((1,1.6,1),center=true,zoom=.95);

// Step 1: construct the base A,B,C on the plane z=0
real a=6, b=5, c=4; 
triple B=(0,0,0), C=(a,0,0);
// Abc is the projection of A on the segment BC
triple Abc=barycentric(B,C,O,1/(a^2+c^2-b^2),1/(a^2+b^2-c^2),0);
real bt=abs(Abc-B);
real hbc=sqrt(c*c-bt*bt);
triple A=Abc+hbc*dir(90,90);

draw(A--Abc,red);
draw(A--B--C--cycle);
label("$A$",A,plain.S);
label("$B$",B,plain.E);
label("$C$",C,plain.W);
label("$A_{bc}$",Abc,plain.N,red);

// Step 2: get the top point D
real at=6, bt=7, ct=4; 
// H is the projection of D on the base ABC
real Sdab=Heron(at,bt,c);
real Sdbc=Heron(bt,ct,a);
real Sdca=Heron(ct,at,b);
triple H=barycentric(A,B,C,1/(Sdab^2+Sdca^2-Sdbc^2),1/(Sdab^2+Sdbc^2-Sdca^2),1/(Sdca^2+Sdbc^2-Sdab^2));
real ha=abs(H-A);
real hd=sqrt(at*at-ha*ha);
triple D=H+hd*Z;
draw(D--A^^D--B^^D--C);
draw(D--H,blue);
label("$D$",D,plain.N);
label("$H$",H,plain.W,blue); dot(H);
```

**PS1**: Why Asymptote and why not TikZ? That drawing way of using `barycentric coordinate` can be coded in several drawing languages. TikZ does has `barycentric coordinate`; but its computation is quite weak, `Dimension too large` error may happen, even in 2D when I had tried drawing the Euler line of a triangle)! Asymptote has better accuracy, and available for 3D.

**PS2**: There is another way based on origami, described in a book of Polya. I will do it in free time later.

Comment: You wrote "Full code (still some mistake ^^)" and " I will do it in free time later." When you post correct answer?

Comment: Peter: As I said: "in free time later". There is a math formula in my last code that I am not sure. If you read my code, you will find that formula. By the way, even you have accepted an answer, I recommend you upvote @Juan Castano's nice TikZ answer; there is only one vote from me so far

Comment: I do not understand you. You wrote "why not TikZ" and "@Juan Castano's nice TikZ answer".

Comment: @Peter: Aha, tt's my subjective opinion, oriented to broad scope of many other figures. It does not conflict with my comment about some nice TikZ figure.

Comment: @Peter: I add a new code, all calculations are only in Asymptote.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This is a two steps approach, first using `tkz-euclide` to (graphically) obtain S point, and then a simply Ti*k*Z 3d drawing with the tetradhedron.

**Fisrt step** (`tkz-euclide`)

Here I'm finding the horizontal projection F of the point S, and the height of the tetradhedron FS. I'm using descriptive geometry, and specifically auxiliary inclined views.

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% triangle ABC
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
\tkzInterCC[R](A,4cm)(B,5cm)
\tkzGetFirstPoint{C}
\tkzCompass[color=red,delta=10](A,C)
\tkzCompass[color=red,delta=10](B,C)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
% triangle ABS1
\tkzInterCC[R](A,6cm)(B,7cm)
\tkzGetSecondPoint{S1}
\tkzCompass[color=red,delta=10](A,S1)
\tkzCompass[color=red,delta=10](B,S1)
% triangle ACS2
\tkzInterCC[R](A,6cm)(C,8cm)
\tkzGetFirstPoint{S2}
\tkzCompass[color=red,delta=5](A,S2)
\tkzCompass[color=red,delta=5](B,S2)
\tkzDrawSegments[blue](B,S1 S1,A A,S2 S2,C)
% points D,E,F,G,H
\tkzDefPointBy[projection = onto A--B](S1)
\tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzDrawLine[dashed,add= 2cm and 1cm](S1,D)
\tkzDefPointBy[projection = onto A--C](S2)
\tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzDrawLine[dashed,add= 1cm and 1cm](S2,E)
\tkzInterLL(S1,D)(S2,E)
\tkzGetPoint{F}
\tkzInterLC(A,C)(E,S2)
\tkzGetFirstPoint{G}
\tkzInterLC(F,S1)(E,S2)
\tkzGetFirstPoint{H}
\tkzDrawLine[add=0 and 1cm](A,G)
\tkzDrawArc(E,S2)(G)
% draw right angles
\tkzMarkRightAngle(D,F,S2)
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,E,S2)
% draw points
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,E,S1,S2,F,G,H)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,E,F,G,H)
\tkzLabelPoint(S1){$S_1$}
\tkzLabelPoint(S2){$S_2$}
% lengths
\tkzGetPointCoord(F){f}
\tkzCalcLength[cm](F,H)\tkzGetLength{dFH}
\tkzLabelPoint(-5,5)  {$F(\pgfmathprint{\fx},\pgfmathprint{\fy})$}
\tkzLabelPoint(-5,4.5){$h=\overline{FH}=\pgfmathprint{\dFH}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image]

**Second step** (Ti*k*Z)

Now I have determined S, approximately (-2/3,-3/2,5.77083). So the rest is only choosing the view and placing the points:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d} % not needed if we only draw the tetrahedron
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={30}{-25},line cap=round,line join=round]
% coordinates
\coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0,4,0);
\coordinate (S) at (-2/3,-3/2,5.77083); % see above tkz-euclide code

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% this is only for showing where is everything %
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  \draw[gray] (-2,-2) grid (4,5);
\end{scope}
\coordinate (F) at (-2/3,-3/2,0);
\draw[blue,dashed] (F) -- (S);
\fill (F) circle (1pt) node [left]  {$F$};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% lines
\draw[blue,thick,dashed] (A) -- (B);
\draw[blue,thick] (C) -- (A) -- (S) -- (C) -- (B) -- (S);
% points
\fill (A) circle (1pt) node [left]  {$A$};
\fill (B) circle (1pt) node [right] {$B$};
\fill (C) circle (1pt) node [below] {$C$};
\fill (S) circle (1pt) node [above] {$S$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the final output:
[image]

Comment: nice grid! Could you explain more how you use descriptive geometry to calculate the foot `F` of the altitude `SF` ? I just guess it is a bit involving with origami way in Polya's book

Comment: @BlackMild, I'm following this procedure: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632936/cleverest-construction-of-a-dodecahedron-icosahedron/1480167#1480167. Take a look specifically at the second picture, which is what I'm drawing but with triangles instead of pentagons. All the triangles are easy to draw as we know the lengths.